# VBA: search bookmarks with Regex

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I have a lot of bookmarked tables in MS Word, named "step", "step1", "step_01", etc. What I need from VBA, is to select all of those tables by bookmarks, and I have to use Regex for this. The thing is, that I managed only to select the "step" table. How can I use Regex in here correctly?
My code:

```
    Function GetTable(sTableName As String) As Table
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetTable = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(sTableName).Range.Tables(1)
End Function

Sub TestTableWithName()
    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim regexObject As RegExp
    Set regexObject = New RegExp
    With regexObject
        .Pattern = "step\w"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    Set myTable = GetTable("step")
    If Not myTable Is Nothing Then
        myTable.Range.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot select non-contiguous ranges with VBA, so if you want to select all tables matching your criteria, you can’t. If you want to do something with the tables you can do that one at a time, but you don’t need RegEx. You need to loop through the bookmarks collection and test if the name is like “step”

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Actually I thought, that I could just create a title "step", and then all generated tables have the same title. but how can I find all tables by title?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "title" - the `Title` property of a table (`tbl.Title`)? a heading above the table? a heading inside the table?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub FindBookmarkedTables()
    Dim bmk As Bookmark, myTable As Table
    For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If Left(bmk.Name, 4) = "step" Then Set myTable = bmk.Range.Tables(1)
    Next bmk
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how the bookmark has been applied.  This response assumes that the bookmark range encompasses the Table range.

The function GetTables returns a collection of all Tables that have a bookmark which includes the text ipBookMarkText

```
Public Sub Test()

    
    Dim myColl As Collection
    Set myColl = GetTables("Step")
    
End Sub

Public Function GetTables(ByVal ipBookmarkText As String) As Collection

    Dim myTables As Collection
    Set myTables = New Collection
    
    Dim myTable As Table
    
    For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    
        Debug.Print myTable.Range.Tables.Item(1).Range.Bookmarks.Item(1).Name
        If InStr(LCase$(myTable.Range.Tables.Item(1).Range.Bookmarks.Item(1).Name), LCase$(ipBookmarkText)) Then
        
            myTables.Add myTable
            
        End If
        
    Next

    Set GetTables = myTables

End Function
```

If you **DO** need to use regex for some unfathomable reason, then use the string obtained by the '.Name' method as the source string for the regex.